# iOS layout column to row

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uistackview

i'm working on an ipad app and i need some help for the layout of one screen :

the screen have to display 3 columns in landscape
and in portrait only 2 columns and 1 row below.

Between auto-layout and UICollectionView, which is the best approach and how ?

Thanks in advance ^^

---

**Edit 07/25/2016**

i like a lot Matt's proposal and i have began implementing this solution (2 UIStackViews)
but now i'm stuck with the conditional constraints :

my xib is parametrized to be displayed in a landscape simulated metric (not sure it has any consequences but now in case of doubt…)

I've managed to update the root UIStackView axis depending on the orientation (vertical for portrait or horizontal for landscape) by listening the UIDevice orientation change notifications.

I have parametrized this root UIStackView distribution property with 'Fill proportionally' but the view doesn't display very well.
In portrait the bottom "row" view's height is too big and in landscape only the two columns in the child UIStackView can be seen (the last view is out of the right edge of the screen

Answer (score 1):

> the screen have to display 3 columns in landscape and in portrait only 2 columns and 1 row below

Wherever columns and rows are involved, you should consider using UIStackView. You can readily design your entire interface in Interface Builder by putting your views inside UIStackView, possibly even putting the containing UIStackViews inside a UIStackView (for example, to put three columns into a single row). You can use conditional constraints / views to make the interface be different in portrait vs. landscape. Thus the whole behavior you have described will probably require no code at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Between auto-layout and UICollectionView, which is the best approach and how ?

Those really are two very different things. If you have a bunch of items that need to be laid out one after the other, use a collection view with a grid layout. You can use constraints and autolayout to adjust the dimensions of the collection view as the device is rotated, and then let the collection view layout the individual items (cells). The main thing you'll probably need to do to make that work well is to adjust the size of the cells so that the spacing between them stays consistent.